# Barplot and line plot in seaborn/matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas df as follows:

```
Date            Col1       Col2
2022-01-01      5          10000
2022-02-01      7          65000
2022-03-01      10         9500
```

I want to create a plot such that the `xaxis` is `Date` and the `Col1` is a barplot and `Col2` is a lineplot.

How can I do this in python? Open to try seaborn or matplotlib.

The `Date` is a `pd.datetime` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the two scales are vastly different, create a [secondary y-axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html).

Since bar plots are categorical, seaborn converts the `x` dates to ordinal ticks. That means matplotlib date formatters will no longer work on them, so it's better to format the date strings beforehand, e.g., [`dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) or [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

Also since seaborn changes the x-axis to ordinal ticks, it's simplest to create the lines with a [`pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) (but if you really want to use a [`lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), reset the index and set `x` to the numeric range).

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx() # secondary y-axis

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date # or dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

sns.barplot(x='Date', y='Col1', data=df, ax=ax1) # on primary ax1
sns.pointplot(x='Date', y='Col2', color='#333', data=df, ax=ax2) # on secondary ax2

# sns.lineplot(x='index', y='Col2', color='#333', data=df.reset_index(), ax=ax2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Especially for such a detailed explanation